# How to fetch aws ecs container ip address in nodejs project

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, containers, amazon-ecs

I have uploaded my API project (Node.js project) to AWS ECS container and my project contains swagger documentation. In swagger I want to indicate the current host Ip address that the API is run on but I cannot find the right code to fetch it. There is a solution for that? since I have managed to implement it on .NetCore API.

How does it looks right now:
[image: How does it looks right now]

Thx in advance.

Comment: A better/easier solution is to change your Node.js app configs to NOT include the `host` field in the generated OpenAPI definition (instead of adding `host: localhost:4000` as it seems). Without a defined `host`, Swagger UI will automatically point to the current host.

Comment: Is this not running behind a load balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of AWS ECS metadata endpoint `http://172.17.0.1:51678/v1/metadata` from an ECS task to fetch details about the container instance. The details fetched can then be used to get the private/public ip address of the instance. Example:

```
import http from 'http';
import util from 'util';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

export const getIPAddresses = async () => {
  try {
    let options: any = {
      hostname: '172.17.0.1',
      port: 51678,
      path: '/v1/metadata',
      method: 'GET'
    }
    let containerInstanceDetails: any = await httpGet(options);
    containerInstanceDetails = JSON.parse(containerInstanceDetails);
    const cluster = containerInstanceDetails["Cluster"];
    const containerInstanceArn = containerInstanceDetails["ContainerInstanceArn"];
    const containerInstanceUUID = containerInstanceArn.split('/')[2];
    let params: any = {
      cluster: cluster,
      containerInstances: [containerInstanceUUID]
    }

    if (!AWS.config.region) {
      AWS.config.update({
        region: <your_aws_region>
      });
    }

    const ecs = new AWS.ECS({ 'region': <your_aws_region> });
    const ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ 'region': <your_aws_region> });

    const describeContainerInstancesAsync = util.promisify(ecs.describeContainerInstances).bind(ecs);
    const describeInstancesAsync = util.promisify(ec2.describeInstances).bind(ec2);
    let data = await describeContainerInstancesAsync(params);
    const ec2InstanceId = data.containerInstances[0].ec2InstanceId;

    params = {
      InstanceIds: [
        ec2InstanceId
      ]
    }

    data = await describeInstancesAsync(params);
    return [data.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PrivateIpAddress, data.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicIpAddress];
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function httpGet(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(options, response => {
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      response.on('data', data => {
        resolve(data);
      });
    }).on('error', error => {
      reject(error.message);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a means of obtaining this metadata that does not rely upon static IPs: using environment variables set by ECS in the container. If you're using a recent version of your platform (Fargate or EC2), you can get the endpoint via `$ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4`

If you're using an earlier version, `$ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI` is available.

See [the AWS docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20230522120438/https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html) for specific information regarding returned JSON and various versions of the endpoint.